# How to apply UIPinchGesture on UIView?

Tags: uiview, ios6, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have one `UIView` which hold one `UIImage` .
I want to apply `UIPinchGesture` on this UIVIew `Programatically`.
I want to resize this `UIView`.

I am adding

```
 UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = 
  [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                            action:@selector(handlePinch:)];
 [pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self]; 
 [frameView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
```

and

```
-(void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender{
}
```

But, I am applying it first time, so anyone help me out of this.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIPinchGestureRecogniser` has a `property` called `scale` which is the `scale` factor between the `CGPoints` of two touches. You can make use of this property.

Add this code in your handlePinch: selector method

```
-(void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    sender.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(sender.view.transform, 
                                                   sender.scale, 
                                                   sender.scale);
    sender.scale = 1.0;
}
```

As given in the documentation,

> The scale value is an absolute value that varies over time. It is not the delta value from ?the last time that the scale was reported. Apply the scale value to the state of the view when the gesture is first recognized—do not concatenate the value each time the handler is called.

So we need to reset the scale value to 1.0 .

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        [gestureRecognizer view].transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], [gestureRecognizer scale], [gestureRecognizer scale]);
        [gestureRecognizer setScale:1];
    }



}
```

For more details refer [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html).